# python add sign in recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I created a recursive function that sums digits of a number n, I want to add a negative sign to the return if n is negative, I only could create the sign outside the function it self because inside the function the sign is changing with every recursive call, Is there any way to calculate the sign inside the function it self?
here is my code

```
def sum1ton (n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    return n%10 + sum1ton (n//10)

    
n = int(input())
sign = -1 if n<0 else 1
print (f'Sum of digits of {n} = {sign * sum1ton(abs(n))}')
```

.................................................................

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you provide some example inputs and outputs? At which point in the recursion do you want to determine the sign? First call or last call?

Comment: @bc1155 I think that he wants sum1ton(-x) = -sum1ton(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the recursive function an inner function of `sum1ton()`:

```py
def sum1ton(n):
    n = int(n)
    sign = -1 if n<0 else 1
    def inner(n):
        if n < 10:
            return n
        return n%10 + sum1ton (n//10)
    return sign * inner(abs(n))
    

n = input()
print (f'Sum of digits of {n} = {sum1ton(n)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot at the same time require a recursive function to work in (sign-less) digits and to propagate the sign, e.g. `sum1ton(-123)` is not `-1 + 2 + 3`, but `-(1 + 2 + 3) = -sum1ton(123)`. If you drop the recursive requirement, I suggest

```py
def sum1ton(n):
    return (+1 if n >= 0 else -1) * sum(int(i) for i in str(abs(n)))
```

Comment: Note this is ~20% faster than the recursive solution, but it cannot be generalized to non-standard bases (but to bases 2, 8 and 16).

Answer (score 0):

I believe we can do this without a store and restore of the sign, nor an inner function.  Your problems here are:

```
n % 10
n // 10
```

as they don't preserve the digits we need with negative numbers:

```
>>> 123 % 10
3
>>> -123 % 10
7

>>> 123 // 10
12
>>> -123 // 10
-13
```

So instead, we need to substitute `math.fmod()` for `%` (modulus) and `int(n / 10)` for `n // 10`:

```
from math import fmod

def sum1ton(n):
    if -10 < n < 10:
        return n

    return int(fmod(n, 10)) + sum1ton(int(n / 10))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> sum1ton(1234567890)
45
>>> sum1ton(-1234567890)
-45
>>>
```